# Why is sbt-osgi adding Include-Resource directives to my MANIFEST.MF?

Tags: scala, sbt, osgi-bundle, bnd

I have an **sbt** project configured (via `build.sbt`) to generate an OSGI bundle (using the **sbt-osgi** plugin).

For some reason, the generated `MANIFEST.MF` contains an `Include-Resource` directive pointing to the (completely empty) "resource" subdirectories in my build directory (`src/main/resources` and `target/scala_2.10/resource_managed/main`, specifically), despite the fact that I have done nothing to tell it to do this (and I definitely don't want my artifacts pointing to locations in my home directory).

Why is **sbt-osgi** doing this, and, more importantly, how can I get it to stop?

My `build.sbt` can be found here: https://github.com/reggert/reb4s/blob/1cd91fb82aa978b2f202c618ca6403a66c15f8d7/build.sbt

Answer (score 0):

It has been several months since I utilized the OSGI plugin, but I think I can recall enough to get you on track.  First, be aware that it is [BND](http://www.aqute.biz/Bnd/Bnd) which is doing all of the hard work here.  The sbt plugin is just a wrapper.  There is some discussion regarding the `Include-Resource` header.  I believe you can set this header to `None` or an empty string with the plugin's `additionalHeaders` setting.

Comment: I tried adding this line:

`OsgiKeys.additionalHeaders := Map("Include-Resource" -> "")`


but it had no apparent effect.

Comment: This seems like it's probably a bug in sbt-osgi. "Include-Resource" isn't a legitimate OSGi MANIFEST header. It's a BND configuration parameter. Somehow it's getting set as an OSGi header, though.

Comment: I just confirmed that it IS a bug, and it can be fixed by making a one-character change to the sbt-osgi source! :-D

Comment: Awesome!  Give them a pull request and save us all future headache :)

Comment: Hi all. Just FYI. I wrote OSGi plugin six month ago. It is allow manifest generation via BND and OBR and P2 dependencies resolution via Tycho API too. It is not mature enough for public but it stable enough for this message. Located at https://github.com/digimead/sbt-osgi-manager Examples are in src/sbt-test and other projects like https://github.com/digimead/digi-TABuddy-model/blob/master/build.sbt Hope it would be useful for someone.